# Ruby on Rails / Timezone in config/application.rb seems doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get a time of users action.
However, it seems return default UTC time even I changed timezone as seoul(UTC +9).

Here are what I did.

in

> config/application.rb

put codes as follow.(change default time_zone to seoul)

> config.time_zone = 'Seoul'
>
> config.active_record.default_timezone = :local

then, run

> rails c
>
> Time.now

I expect time as UTC +9, but it shows UTC +0

Saved time of users action in data is also shown UTC +0.

How can I get time as UTC +9?, is there anything that I need to set?

Comment: It's normal for everything in the database to be utc. Time.zone.now should be in the desired tinezone

Comment: Problem solved!! It's server time_zone problem. Thanks for your comment!   sudo rm /etc/localtime
 
 sudo ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Seoul /etc/localtime

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
config.time_zone = 'Korea Time Zone (UTC+09:00)'
```

Comment: It seems not proper format of config setting, but thanks for your comment!!