# Ruby on Rails - Make ALL time (Time, DateTime), etc, as Central

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm using Delayed::Job for part of my Rails project and what's extremely frustrating and confusing is that the job isn't running at the specified time. I have a feeling because it's scheduling the jobs to run at UTC time instead of CST.

In my `config/application.rb` file I have the following two lines:

```
config.time_zone = "Central Time (US & Canada)"
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

However, when I look at the list of delayed jobs and their `updated_at`, `created_at` and `run_at` times, they're completely different time zones. They're UTC, about 6 hours off.

Is there any way that I can just make everything CST, globally? This is annoying and very confusing because now I have to try to figure out how to convert times, hope things match up, etc.

Comment: What timezone is the server set to?

Comment: @MichaelEconomy Central.

** EDIT ** Nevermind. I thought it was at least. I'll fix this and then try again.

Comment: Did you see the following link? Maybe, you have server time_zone problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27942019/ruby-on-rails-timezone-in-config-application-rb-seems-doesnt-work?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following?

```
Time.now.in_time_zone("Central Time (US & Canada)")
```

You can find the names of the ActiveSupport time zones by doing:

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.map(&:name)
```

or for just US

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones.map(&:name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should consider storing the time in UTC and manipulate it from UTC (normally this is a lot easier and why it is convention). If a user needs to view the time, then show central time from a view.

Comment: It's still a little too confusing. Does this mean I now have to change my server's time to UTC and add even more confusion with other apps? Is there not an easy way to just convert everything to CST?

Comment: If you are using Active Record, it stores everything in UTC time by default. Does your server somehow override this and change everything to central time?